# Missing Template/Partial Error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've already checked the other questions that ask this and I haven't been able to resolve my issue.

Error:

```
Missing partial tasks/_form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],
:variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee,
:jbuilder]}. Searched in:
* "/Users/brendan/Documents/Ruby/project_manager/app/views"
```

My show.html.erb that is rendering the view:

```
<div id="todo_items_wrapper">
  <%= render @project.tasks %>
  <div id="form">
    <%= render "tasks/form" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The view is titled _form.html.erb and contains the code:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.tasks.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "New Task" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have a file _form.html.erb in your app\views\tasks folder?   

If you used scaffolding to build that part of your app, it should be there.

Comment: What folder is your partial in?

Answer (score 0):

If the _form partial is in the folder tasks, you should be able to just call `render "form"`

Is it in a different folder than show.html.erb?

Answer (score 0):

If your **show.html.erb** and **tasks/_form.html.erb** both resides under `views/projects/`, then you should render your partial as follows:

```
<%= render "projects/tasks/form" %>
```